# Solve the equation $\sigma{(n)}=n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisor-sum

> Find all positive $n$ such that
>   $$\sigma{(n)}=n$$
>   where $\sigma{(n)}$ is the sum-of-divisors function.

We write this equation as following:
$$\dfrac{\sigma{(n)}}{n}=\sum_{d|n}\dfrac{1}{d}=1$$
I checked that the number $n=1$ is one solution, but are there others?

Comment: abandon: A question you posted today [was discussed on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/20980/perplexity-about-an-imo-question). I thought that it would be good to let you know about the meta discussion. Since I cannot ping you on a deleted post, I chosen another post of yours to make you aware of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $n$ is a divisor of $n$. What happens if $n$ has any other divisors?

Answer (score 1):

If $n\neq 1$, then $n$ and $1$ would be different divisors of $n$, so the sum of divisors would be at least $n+1.$ Hence, only solution is $n=1$.